# docker Cannot find module 'Sequelize'

Tags: node.js, docker, npm

Getting below error after deploying docker image:

> Cannot find module 'Sequelize'

Directory structure:

```
src
views
Dockerfile
package.json
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8
ENV PORT 3000
EXPOSE 3000

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["npm", "run", "prod"]
```

Package.json:

```
{
"name": "api",
"version": "0.0.0",
"private": true,
"main": "src/loader.js",
"scripts": {
  "dev": "nodemon",
  "prod": "node src/loader.js"
},
"dependencies": {
  "sequelize": "^4.38.0",
  "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
  "cors": "^2.8.4",
  "debug": "~2.6.9",
  "express": "~4.16.0",
  "express-graphql": "^0.6.12",
  "graphql": "^0.13.2",
  "graphql-relay": "^0.5.5",
  "graphql-sequelize": "^9.0.1",
  "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
  "jade": "^1.11.0",
  "morgan": "~1.9.0",
  "mysql2": "^1.6.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "nodemon": "^1.18.3"
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be a typo, ie can you verify that you are using `require('sequelize')`  instead of `require('Sequelize')`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to explicitly add the module in your package.json

```
$ npm install --save sequelize
```

If the module is declared, it will be found by the dependent module that is causing you that error.

Hope it helps!